# FogBugz - Filter List by date range using BETWEEN

Tags: fogbugz

Is there a way in FogBugz to filter a list of cases which have been opened/resolved/closed between a given date range?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Btw, FogBugz has its own support forum at http://our.fogbugz.com/default.asp?fogbugz and new StackOverflow-like forum at http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for (in your FogBugz):

> Opened:"September/1/2009..today"

See [Searching in FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/docs/70/topics/basics/Searchingforcases.html) for more.